# Generate LINQ DataContext from XML, XSD, or C# class

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xsd, datacontext

I have a massive set of classes I need to create from an XML file that I'd really not like to do by hand. What I'd really like to do is somehow generate a LINQ DataContext so I can use VisualStudio to build a SQL database from the DataContext.

I'm aware that I can generate XSD and C# classes from the XML file, but are there any tools to generate proper SQL Database tables or LINQ DataContext from those?

Comment: I think it may be better to create SQL scripts directly. Surely it'll be more work to create a valid DataContext class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/ to generate C# classes from your XSD. Don't forget to enable Serialization and GenerateXMLAttributes. Set ColllectionObject Type to a type that implements ICollection, for instance List, don't use IList.

Next, implement your DbContext as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe LINQ to SQL supports creating a database from a model of any kind. Entity Framework in .NET 4.0 does.

Also, be aware that not all XML schemas map to valid relational database structures.

Answer (score -1):

Open an XSD file in VS, create a DataSet in VS, then copy the XSD file into the dataset both in designer mode. That'll generate the a typed DataContext.

Comment: He's talking LINQ to SQL. DataSet generates TableAdapter, not DataContext.